# RedirectToAction in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 MVC projects. One of them is API and I want from this one to pass data into another project in the same solution. How is it possible?

I have added the reference in the head of the controller

```
public class ProspectController : Controller
{
    DataContext db = new DataContext();
    // GET: Prospect
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
        // The Controller in the other project 
        TestController t = new TestController();

        //return to the Controller in the other project   
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Project2.TestController", new {id=4});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that you can't do what you are trying to do. `RedirectToAction` uses the route table to create the URL, which you can't do because you're dealing with two different applications and two different route tables.

What you *can* do is use the `RedirectResult` to send the user to another URL entirely, whether it be in the same application or a different one.

```
return Redirect("http://OtherSite/Test/Index?id=4");
```